# Laravel $request->file() returns null

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

having trouble trying to upload files using Laravel on the back-end.

#### Issue

Laravel `$request->file()` method returns null.

#### Setup

I build up an AJAX request using [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent), debugged the request and everything seems fine. The `Content-Length` changes depending on the image I add, indicating an image has been added to the request. The `Content-Type` is also set to `multipart/form-data`.

```
// request headers
Content-Length:978599
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; 

// request payload
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="item-keymoment.png"
Content-Type: image/png
```

But I'm unable to get the file in Laravel. Using `$request->file('files')` returns `NULL`, but if I debug the `$_FILES` array, I noticed that a my file has been uploaded.

```
dd($request->file('files'))
// NULL

dd($_FILES);
// array:1 [
//   "files" => array:5 [
//     "name" => "item-keymoment.png"
//     "type" => "image/png"
//     "tmp_name" => "/tmp/phpipbeeM"
//     "error" => 0
//     "size" => 978274
//   ]
// ]

dd($request->files->all())
// []
```

What might be causing Laravel to ignore the file?
`Content-Type` of the input file not being `application/octet-stream`?

**Below have answered the question.**

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You should add to the form tag `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

For example:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('back.post.new')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
.............
</form>
```

Adding it you can use your custom Request.

I hope this can you help!

Comment: I was looking at this answer and I thought I have it but I had two files - one for create and another for edit screen. So after couple hours I saw this answer again and realized that I should double check and that was exactly the problem. I am dumb XD

Comment: even after years of experience, I need someone to remind me to add this :D

Answer (score 7):

Noticed that the `$request` object I was receiving in the Controller method was an Instance of `JsonRequest`, which is a custom class (*empty for now*) that extends `Illuminate\Http\Request`.

And it's implemented as:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class JsonRequest extends Request {
}
```

But if I change:

```
// from
use App\Http\Requests\JsonRequest;
public function add_background_image (JsonRequest $request) {
  dd($request->file('files'))
  // NULL
}

// to
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
public function add_background_image (Request $request) {
  dd($request->file('files'))
  // UploadedFile {#266
  //   -test: false
  //   -originalName: "item-keymoment.png"
  //   -mimeType: "image/png"
  //   -size: 978274
  //   -error: 0
  //   ...
  // }
}
```

I get the desired input file. For now switching the instance of `$request` solves my issue

> But I don't understand why/how extending `Illuminate\Http\Request` with an empty Class breaks things.
>   **Can someone explain?**

My intention with subclassing `Illuminate\Http\Request` was to be able to attach methods on `$requests` for dealing with exceptions/errors in a unified way for API requests. Such as when in deployment show exception messages, but in production return a fixed message.

**Is there different/better/more Laravel way of doing that?**

I think will just create a JsonController instead of extending Request.

Comment: try adding a constructor so you can link `JsonRequest` with `Request`

Comment: did you injected Request in the method ?

Comment: @AniruddhaChakraborty how I go about doing that?

Well I'm starting to figure out that the `app/Http/Requests` are used mainly as `FormRequests` to remove validation from controllers.

But with `JsonRequest` I wanted the `$request` instance to have additonal messages with handling exceptions and returning error messages.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem ONLY on the server. The image is stored in the `$_FILES` variable which points to a physical directory in your `php.ini` file. Make sure you have the correct permissions for this directory.

php.ini:

`upload_tmp_dir = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php`

Answer (score 0):

Check your `php.ini` settings for:

- `file_uploads`
- `upload_max_filesize`
- `max_file_uploads`

I had mine turned off. I guess that makes it quietly wipe out the file.

Or run `php -i | grep --color=always upload` to check your current settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, had added the enctype="multipart/form-data" part in the form, tried all the solutions posted here...

But In my case the problem was in the javascript. I was creating the <input type"file" /> dinamically from another input, and was copying the props file object from one another, posting it to laravel and then in laravel $request->input was null:

```
$('#take-picture').on('change', function (){
 let props = $(this).prop('files');
 ...
 let $input = $('<input type="file" class="d-none" />');
 $input.prop('name', 'image_one').prop('files', props);
 $(this).val(''); //This is the problem in my case
 ...
 $form.append($input);
 $form.submit();
```

The problem was in this line:

```
$(this).val('');
```

Because I was obtaining the props object and assigning it to the created input, and the setting it to null to delete the selected value in the original input. but this object is obtained **by reference**, so when I was seleting it from the original input, I **was deleting** it from the newly created too, and so when posting the form, laravel got null.

So the solution was simply to obtain a clone of the props object and use it (I used the solution to clone a FileList posted in this answer:
[Is it possible to update FileList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52078853/is-it-possible-to-update-filelist)

```
let props = $(this).prop('files')
...
let cloneProps = new FileListItems(props);
$input.prop('name', 'image_' + image_index).prop('files', cloneProps)
```

Hope it helps somebody!