# Error uploading image in Laravel 9 getClientOriginalExtension() on null

Tags: laravel-9

When I upload my image in Laravel 9, I get the following error.

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null

**Controller**

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $data = new food;
    $image = $request->image;
    $imagename = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $request->image->move('foodimage', $imagename);
    $data->image = $imagename;
}
```

Comment: copy the view code and paste here

Comment: Had same issue found solution here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38226875/laravel-request-file-returns-null